# CSS missing while using ACF form in frontend

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF and wants to create a form in frontend for user profile. i get all the data but there is some problem with css. i have tried this

```
<?php
acf_form_head();
wp_head();
?>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main" class="content-area">
        <?php
        $options = array(
            'post_id' => 'user_' . get_current_user_id(),
            'field_groups' => array(18),
            'form' => true,
            'return' => add_query_arg('updated', 'true', get_permalink()),
            'html_before_fields' => '',
            'html_after_fields' => '',
            'submit_value' => 'Update'
        );
        acf_form($options);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

here is my screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXG52.png)

Comment: What is the problem with your css?

Comment: i have uploaded my screenshot you can check. button is not appearing properly and design missing

Comment: We're going to need a little bit more information I'm afraid. The screenshot isn't much help because we don't know what we are looking at. Maybe you could add the html that's produced in the browser and any css that might be related.

Comment: the html code is so long ,so i cant send here..you can see there is a hyperlink add row that is not a anchor tag that's a button but due tto css issue it is totally incomplete

Comment: can you please send me the working code

Comment: can anyone help me to get this code